# How to quantify a relationship so that a small value increases the result and a larger value decrease the result?

Tags: analysis, arithmetic, mathematical-modeling

The title pretty much says it all but let me break it down. I thoroughly appreciate any help.

I'm trying to quantify a relationship between the difference in peaks and troughs of a wave function and the value of that function at some point such that the smaller the difference between the peaks and troughs the greater the result but I'm not sure how to model that.

Example.
Imagine a sin wave that is projected onto a cartesian plane where the x axis represents time and the y axis represents the value of the sin function at any given x.

Extrapolated. 
Now imagine different wave functions that have non consistent peaks and troughs. I want to average the differences before a given x, and relate that average to the value of the wave function at x but I want smaller values of the average to have a greater effect on the end result.

Thank you so much for your time and hopefully knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship can be modeled with division with the average as the divisor. The smaller the divsor the larger the result.